# How to remove stuck M/T from 2001-2005 Honda Civic (EM2 coupe)

Tags: honda, civic, clutch, manual-transmission

Trying to remove the manual transmission from a 2004 EM2 Civic. Everything is loosened/undone and she should be ready to slide right off but it won't budge.

(Starter motor is removed, both central motor/transmission mounts and subframe are off, all 5 bolts that hold the transmission to the motor are out. Bottom brace and flywheel inspection cover are off. Transmission is out of the left side mount... I'm sure that is all there is.)

So how does one deal with a M/T transmission that won't come off without causing damage? Any specific spots that allow for safely prying (There's no gap yet to get anything in between and I see no leverage points anywhere) ? Perhaps some tips or tricks from a expierienced Honda tech for this model ?

Comment: You've got the engine/transmission assembly out of the car? I'm pretty sure you cannot do it with the engine in there. I was able to get the engine out through the top of my 2003 Civic by itself, but I don't think there's any way to get just the transmission out by itself.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The service manual has one remove the entire subframe, which i did (but the engine stays in the car, resting on some supports). There's plenty of room, it just won't separate from the engine.

Comment: If you've gone that far, you'd be way better off to just remove the entire thing, then break it apart away from the car. You can see and get to everything much easier. I believe it would drop right out the bottom.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no another bolt tucked away in a place difficult to see or reach?

Comment: @jwh20 Yes, there's only 5. 2 on top, 2 on the side facing the radiator and 1 that's in backwards from the rest on the other side. Starter's out and the bottom brace and flywheel inspection cover are off.

Comment: Why does it seem like there's more bolts then that? It has been a while since I removed the D17 engine from the Civic I used to have, but it seems to me there are more bolts than five. I'd do a *very good* once over to see if you haven't missed something. I know when I pulled mine, it separated very easily. BTW, sometimes you have to do things on instinct and not by what the service manual says. JMHO.

Comment: I'm watching a video where they are taking the trans and engine out as a unit. I'm pretty sure I'm seeing at least three bolts on the front (intake) side of the engine. I'm pretty sure there are at least three more in the back (intake side). Are you sure you've removed the correct bolts and/or you're trying to separate the engine and transmission at the correct spot? If you are removing the correct bolts, I'm thinking you've got several more to go before it will split.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Those 3 bolts on either side you're talking about are for the mounts that attach engine/transmission to the subframe. Subframe's completely off, including both of those mounts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She's out. It was stuck on 1 of the dowels (radiator side), which was corroded to heck. I managed to get an initial gap working the seam with putty knives and penetrating oil and then I noticed it was stuck in the dowel area when rocking it up and down.

I fabricated 2 metal blocks, one to bolt onto the transmission and 1 on the engine, in the holes where the front engine/transmission mount bolts should go. Then I could use the blocks to put a prybar in between and after a long struggle she was loose.

Never knew 1 stupid dowel could get so stuck.